# Fade UIView color at the top

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a basic `UIView` I created via Interface Builder (`XIB`).

I want to get this effect (in the image: my view above an image):

[image]
How can I make the `UIView`'s background color to fade at the top?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean is adding "gradient" effect to your UIView. To do this, you need to add [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cagradientlayer), you can create a custom `UIView` similar to this:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    private let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        addGradient()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // update gradient
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    }

    private func addGradient() {
        // declaring colors for your gradient:
        // top color is clear
        let topColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        // bottom color is black
        let bottomColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        gradientLayer.frame = self.frame

        // add colors to the gradientLayer:
        gradientLayer.colors = [topColor, bottomColor]

        // change the startPoint and endPoint to make it appears like it should...
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        // add the gradient to your view (which in my case is gradientView)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```